# base-href value being reset to blank in angular-cli?

Tags: angular, angular-cli

It appears that when using angular-cli, the base-href specified in the index.html is set to "", even through I am not specifying --base-href via the command line.

This causes the html5 routing to not work since when accessing /some/other/route on a new request causes the client to be unable to access the .bundles since /some/other/route/.foo is 404?

Wanted to check here before I open up a bug report on github.

Comment: Check the base property on your .angular-cli file

Comment: @DanielNetzer, yes, not specified there. As a work around for now I have specified it to be "/" and all is working well. Not sure if I should open up a bug report or not?

Comment: Well it should be a part of that file, so it keeps the base href for your app on build

Comment: @DanielNetzer I would expect the behavior to leave it alone in the index.html unless you specify it in the configuration.  Right now, if the value is not specified in the configuration it is overriding the value in the index.html from the sane default of '/' to the not-so-helpful value of "" (emptystring).